# Why does GHCi show "Display all 516 posibilities? (y or n)" when I paste code into the terminal?

Tags: haskell

When I copy and past the following code to my terminal

```
myCode :: Int ->[a]->[a]
myCode a [] =[]
myCode a xs
    | a < length xs     = take a xs
    | otherwise = xs :unroll a-length xs xs
```

I get

> Display all 516 possibilities? (y or n)

I think maybe the operation `<` is the source of the problem. In this case, `a` is `Int`, and `length xs` is also of type `Int`. Why can't they be compared?

By the way, the code implements a specified length list. For example:

```
myCode 5 [2,4,5,3,1,3,6,2,6]   -- returns [2,4,5,3,1]
myCode 10 "my"                 -- returns "mymymymymy"
```

Comment: How exactly are you giving your code to GHC?

Comment: I first input " :{ "  ,then copy the code, but terminal only shows the first 3 lines , then shows "Display all 518 possibilities? (y or n)"

Comment: Let's ignoring the otherwise code, it may have some problems,  but even if i make it"otherwise     = [1]", Terminal also warn " "Display all 516 possibilities? (y or n)"

Comment: Are you pressing tab? See [Unix.SE: Shell display all 2588 possibilities](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171489/shell-display-all-2588-possibilities/171498). Use spaces instead.

Comment: Unrelated. Note that `foo a [] = []` can be written as `foo _ [] = []` which makes it more clear that `a` is not used.

Comment: Unrelated. You are probably missing brackets `(` around `a-length xs` in `unroll a-length xs xs`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, using Spaces instead Tab can solve this problem, thank you! @TrebuchetMS

Comment: Could you accept this answer (press the green checkmark next to the voting buttons) so this question appears as 'answered'? Otherwise it appears in the list of unanswered questions.